# Error 9 The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

When to build my website project this morning and got this error:

`Error  9   The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.`

No additional line numbers, project, or file information are displayed, just the error message.  I tried cleaning the solution and opening and closing visual studio (running 2012 beta).  Anyone have any suggestions to how I can get my project to build?

Comment: I just got this error in VS 2008, I did a `Clean` then a `Rebuild All` on the solution and that seemed to make it go away.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually, just selecting the rebuild option is enough to resolve this issue. However you may also need to:

1. adjust your virtual memory settings to make more virtual memory available.
2. exit other applications that are consuming large amounts of virtual memory.
3. it also appears that Microsoft attempted a fix for this in Service Pack 1 for Visual    Studio, although this has not resolved the issue for all people.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/ee53aa77-8cb5-4ca7-a9cc-af9fb7379d5c

Comment: Any idea of the underlying problem is? I checked my own virtual memory and saw that I have 8GB of virtual memory and 8GB of physical memory, so I have doubts whether memory is the real issue here.

Answer (score 3):

Little late to the party but for googlers:
I had this every time I'd do a build, would have to build 3 or 4 times to launch the application. My solution was inside a Dropbox folder & turns out Dropbox was locking the compiled dlls.

Once I'd excluded the bin directories (did obj directories too for good measure) the problem went away.
This may also be the case for antivirus/antimalware programs too.